# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Invalid object name

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to add an array as tvp to sql server. The problem actually exists that there is a function I call inside the stored procedure but the error arises as
"Invalid object name 'IncrementKeyID'". 
My c# code is something like this:

```
   public void key_insert(string[] KeyArray, int count)
    {
        var keyworddt = new DataTable();
        keyworddt.Columns.Add("strKeyword_Name", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 0; i < count;i++ )
            keyworddt.Rows.Add(KeyArray[i]);
        var parameter = new SqlParameter("@Keyword", SqlDbType.Structured);
        parameter.Value = keyworddt;
        parameter.TypeName = "dbo.KeyInsertUDT";
        using (obj)
        {
            obj.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec dbo.usp_KeyInsert @Keyword", parameter);
        }
    }
```

I created the table as

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Tbl_Keyword
    (
     PK_strKeyword_Id varchar(11) not null,
     strKeyword_Name varchar(30) not null,
     PRIMARY KEY (PK_strKeyword_Id)
    );
```

The TVP is created as something like

```
  Create Type KeyInsertUDT as Table 
  (
  strKeyword_Name varchar(30)
  )
```

The function that I created and as well as the stored procedure that calls the function are:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IncrementKeyID
    ()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
    as 
    begin
    DECLARE @PK_strKeyword_Id VARCHAR(11);
    DECLARE @PreFix VARCHAR(10) = 'KEY';
    DECLARE @Id INT;

    SELECT @Id = ISNULL(COUNT(PK_strKeyword_Id),0) + 1 FROM Tbl_Keyword
    SELECT @PK_strKeyword_Id = @PreFix + RIGHT('' + CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)
    RETURN @PK_strKeyword_Id
    END


    Create procedure usp_KeyInsert
    @Keyword dbo.KeyInsertUDT Readonly
    as
    Begin
    insert into dbo.Tbl_Keyword (PK_strKeyword_Id,strKeyword_Name)
     SELECT f1.PK_strKeyword_Id,f2.strKeyword_Name
    FROM
    (SELECT * FROM IncrementKeyID()) AS f1
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT strKeyword_Name FROM @Keyword) AS f2
    End
```

I know the problem lies with the stored procedure but since I am new to the concept I cannot understand where the error lies. In my stored procedure I am basically trying to retrieve the array values and store them in keyword table assigning a unique primary key to it. How do I debug the error?

Comment: call the function in your procedure as `dbo.IncrementKeyID()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke UDFs you need to qualify them by the owning schema-name - so `dbo.IncrementKeyID()`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.IncrementKeyID()
```

Although since this is a scalar UDF, you don't need to use `SELECT`:

```
insert into dbo.Tbl_Keyword (PK_strKeyword_Id,strKeyword_Name)
SELECT dbo.IncrementKeyID(), strKeyword_Name
FROM @Keyword
```

However, it looks like you're simply re-implemented `IDENTITY` in a poor way, introducing a nasty race condition in the process, and making much more expensive to store and query (`varchar(11)` is considerably more expensive to work with than `int`). If possible, just use an `int not null identity(1,1)` column. There is no advantange whatsoever in storing `'KEY27'` rather than `27`. If you  want to prefix the keys: do  that in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, Yes this worked fine and also I need to use varchar so I am doing this way . But there is another problem,when the insert command is invoked the primary key is incremented only once and only that value is trying to be duplicated for other rows. How can I write a code so that for every tvp value inserted in the table primary key is incremented?? Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Amalpriya by using an **identity column**. In the case of a UDF: it is for the server to determine when to call it (unless you use  cross-apply, and please don't do that). Your "I need to use varchar" is frankly: daft. Sorry, but it is. You job as a programmer is sometimes to say "no, that isn't an appropriate design" - and in this case: it isn't. However, as an absolute worst case you could do something like `create table Foo (   __id int not null identity(1,1),   Id as 'KEY' + CONVERT(varchar(8), __id) PERSISTED,     Keyword varchar(30) not null)`, but please let me be clear: that is stupid

Comment: Finally, I went through with your idea of using identity column because using varchar was getting more complicated than expected. Anyway thanks for your help. Saved me from complicating myself and the code